# Arduino: reviewing sensor response when given a command

Tags: arduino, serial-communication

I have a gas sensor (Sprint IR sensor) that measures the CO2 concentration in the atmosphere. I would like the sensor to return current the digital filter setting. According to the sensor manual, I need to input two commands: set the sensor to 'command mode', and have it return the value of the digital filter. The input syntax for setting the command mode is **K 0\r\n**, and that for the digital filter is **a\r\n** (\r\n stand for carriage return and line feed). This is the code I have so far:

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(5,6); // TX, RX pins on my Arduino board
String val = ""; //output string
uint8_t buffer[25]; //initialize char array of 25 spaces
uint8_t ind = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start Serial connection with host
  Serial.println("SprintIR Sample");
  mySerial.begin(9600); //start serial connection with Sensor
  mySerial.write("K 0"); //set 'command mode'
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()> 0) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
  while(mySerial.available()> 0) {
    val = mySerial.read();
    if (buffer[ind-1] == '\n') {
      ind = 0;
      val = "";
      break;
    }
  }
  if (val != "") {
    Serial.println(val);
  }
  val = "";
  ind = 0;
}
```

The manual states that the sensor's response of the digital filter should look like **a 00032\r\n** (32 would be the filter setting, which is what I want). However, my serial monitor shows **32 //newline 49 //newline 10 //newline** each time I send **a\r\n** from my serial monitor.

I have several questions:

1. What needs to be done so that I obtain a response of **a 00032\r\n**?
2. What is the difference between writing `mySerial.write("K 0");` and `mySerial.read("K 0");`? Also, would there be a difference if single quote marks were used instead of double quote marks?

Comment: `mySerial.read("K 0")` makes no sense. `mySerial.read()`returns a single byte. `"` is for strings, ˙'˙ is for characters.